# GPS Location Accuracy Issue

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android app that uses high-resolution GPS data. It's designed to be used in a car, so I'm not too worried about battery life. I've noticed that when I run my app while the stock Google navigation app is running, my GPS data has accuracy within several (< 10) meters.

However, when I run my app without the navigation app, my location data starts off precise, but soon becomes poor (within 1000 m). I have my app in a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` so the CPU keeps running, but the screen can shut off.

Here's how I'm requesting GPS location:

`requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, GPSListener);`

Does anyone know of a way to request data more precisely? The [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) claim this means there is no lower limit on the time or distance between separate GPS calls. But clearly the stock navigation app is doing something differently. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to use the Android NDK? http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html  More direct access to the hardware may be the way to go if you need more precision.  Just a guess, though, and I'm not sure the implications of using the NDK and being able to publish it to the Android Market, if that's the end goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **requestLocationUpdates
      (long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)**
And set the criteria to ACCURACY_HIGH and some other options you may explore. If you are using the WiFi network too then you can also get the cell locations to provide more accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know if I have to do the Wi-Fi location on my own, or is there a library that will aggregate GPS/cell tower/Wi-Fi and give me lat/lon coords?

Comment: Add another `requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)` but this time provider is `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Comment: Since you said thai there is no battery issue so the both provider works, but if not then user `LocationManager.getBestProvider(Criteria criteria, boolean enabledOnly)` to get the best suitable provider that matches the criteria as disscussed above. If you like the answer then please accept it.

Comment: Also, as an FYI, this approach will not work in Froyo. The version of `requestLocationUpdates` that takes in a Criteria requires API Level 9 (Gingerbread).